# Simple algorithm in python fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following program should simply multiply two numbers together and it seems to fail at some point however I am not quite sure where.

```
def multiply(first,second):
  if first == 0:
    second
  else:
    multiply(first - 1,second + second)

def multiplyh(first,second):
    if first == 0:
        0
    else:
        multiply(first,second)




first = int(input("Enter ur first number"))
second = int(input("Enter ur second number"))
print(str(first) + "<- 1 " + str(second) + "<- 2")
print(multiplyh(first,second))
```

I'm sure it's a simple bug however i can't seem to spot it

Comment: What output are you expecting, and what output is it giving you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to write a recursive solution. The following is a partial solution which should help you understand the logic, but you will find that such an approach fails with negative numbers.

```
def multiply(first, second):
    if first:
        return second + multiply(first-1, second)
    else:
        return 0


first = int(input("Enter ur first number"))
second = int(input("Enter ur second number"))
print(str(first) + "<- 1 " + str(second) + "<- 2")
print(multiply(first,second))
```

The following would also cope with negative numbers:

```
def multiply(first, second):
    if first > 0:
        return second + multiply(first-1, second)
    elif first < 0:
        return -second + multiply(first+1, second)
    else:
        return 0

ltests = [(0,0), (0,5), (5,0), (1,5), (3,5), (-3,5), (-4, 5), (-3,-5)]

for first, second in ltests:        
    print multiply(first, second)
```

Which gives the following test results:

```
0 0 0 5 15 -15 -20 15
```

Comment: Doesn't python return the last line of code? I mean it works with `return` however I remember vaguely that python takes the last line and returns it. Is the return specially because it's a recursive approach?

Comment: The return statements are needed in this context. Are you confusing it with running Python interactively at a console?

Comment: Oh no no. I just remembered python doesn't need a return. By "this context" you mean that `return` is needed here because the function returning another one?

Comment: If the `else: return 0` was removed, then Python would automatically return `None` by default. This would then mean the previous call would be `return second + None` which is not valid. Try `print 1 + None`  This is why `0` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You'r code isn't complete:

What is happening inside the first `if` condition inside your `multiply` function ?

But, just add the `return` statement to `multiply(first - 1,second + second)` and `second`, if not this function is not returning anything to your `print` call.

Suggesting you're trying to make your own multiply function from additions, here's your code you're expecting :

```
def multiply(first,second):
    if first == 0:
        return second
    else:
        return multiply(first - 1,second + second)

first = int(input("Enter ur first number "))
second = int(input("Enter ur second number "))
print(str(first) + "<- 1 " + str(second) + "<- 2")
print(multiply(first,second))
```

But it's not the good algorithm to perform an addition based multiplication.

If you're simply looking how to perform a multiplication, you could do `print(first * second)`